# Closing/tabbing between windows using Javascript or HTML

Tags: javascript, html, tabbing

I have a small query. Is it possible to switch between open windows using HTML or JavaScript, for example;

IE open with Intranet. Intranet has a button which when clicked it opens an already running application in this case Citrix Receiver. Basically minimizing the web browser or tabbing across.

Comment: `switch between open windows` open _browser_ windows or _any application_ windows?

Comment: No, you can't control that from JavaScript in the browser. The closest you can come is closing the window (tab) entirely, and even that can only be done in limited circumstances.